# HTTP_REFFERER not show parameters in https website

Tags: php, https

I am using HTTP_REFFERER to get users searched keyword on google
but when they redirect from google to my website this just show

> https://www.google.com

I thing its for ssl certificate

I am set this meta tag for solve it

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

but its not working fine

Comment: `$referer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : 'HTTP_REFERER_UNKNOWN';` _'HTTP_REFERER'
    The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted._ [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: REFERER can be empty or not set due a https, RedirectMatch in .htaccess, a browser restriction and many other situations...

Comment: When a request comes to your server, log the raw HTTP headers.  Look for the referrer header in that log.  Whatever is the value in that header, that's all the information you're given.  No software on your side can change that.